# Adding Keys to a GCP Instance(VM)

Tags: ssh, putty, google-cloud-platform

I have created a GCP instance and want to add SSH keys for use with Putty. I followed their tutorial steb by step. Created the keys via Puttygen as advised and added to the section during instance creation. None worked with putty and even added on the metadata as per their tutorial and still Got the same error as before:

Using username "XXXXX@XXXXXXXXXXXX". Server refused our key

The answers in here and elsewhere seem to systematically copy GCP own tutorials with no much help. I have practiced cloud computing with AWS, Linode, Oracle, and everything was so easily documented even the setups to SSH Access but Google seems a hard one to crack.

Any help on how to go about using GCP with Putty will be greatly appreciated. I don't want to keep using the cloud shell or ssh-in Browswer